# Animating an SCNText in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, arkit

I have an SCNText node displayed in the AR screen. I am trying to animate it by using SCNAction property. But it is not working properly. 
Is there any other way to animate the node?

Also if I want to insert an image in place of the text what should I do? I know I can't add it as a geometry. So is there any other way?

Thank you

```
    func displayText() {

    let textGeo = SCNText(string: "HELLO WORLD", extrusionDepth: 1.0)

    textGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeo)
    textNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0.1,-0.5)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.002,0.002,0.002)

    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

    let action = SCNAction.fadeOpacity(by: 10.0, duration: 5.0)
    textNode.runAction(action)
```

Comment: Please post your code so far...

Comment: Check it now please

Answer (score 4):

An SCNNode's opacity ranges from 0 to 1. As your node starts with an opacity of 1, fading the opacity by 10 will have no effect.

If you want the node to fade out use a value of -1.

Answer (score 0):

please set the opactiy for your text node = 0 befor you add your text node 
and then run your opacity action by 1.0 not by 10.0